error en android studio en activity
(Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': could not resolve com.google.code findbugs)
es en android studio acabo de instalar la version 3.0 ya que la ultima version es demasiado pesada para mi pc

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Hola. ¿La versión 3.0 de qué?, agrega tu build.gradle donde se tienen las dependencias. Recuerda agregar mayor información, revisa [ask], saludos.
